# D3 Monotone Interpolation - Smoothing a line

Tags: d3.js

I was using the following code:

```
var c = d3.line()
.interpolate("monotone")
.x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
.y(function(d) { return y(d.close); });
```

And now that I am updating all my visual studies to D3 version 4 I can't work out how to upgrade the above interpolation.

I want to smooth the line.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is the code using D3 version 4.x:

```
var c = d3.line()
    .curve(d3.curveMonotoneX)
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.close); });
```

You can also use `d3.curveMonotoneY`, depending on the axis you want to preserve the monotonicity.

Here is the [API](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape/blob/master/README.md#curveMonotoneX).
Link to changes [v3 to v4](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md).